# Using congruences, show $\frac{1}{5}n^5 + \frac{1}{3}n^3 + \frac{7}{15}n$ is integer for every $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Using congruences, show that the following is always an integer for every integer
value of $n$:
$$\frac{1}{5}n^5 + \frac{1}{3}n^3 + \frac{7}{15}n.$$

Comment: Please don't state your questions as orders or assignments to the group. If you have a question, ask it like a question, not like an order.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Lets show that $P(n)=3n^5+5n^3+7n$ is divisible by 15 for every $n$.  To do this, we will show that it is divisible by $3$ and $5$ for every $n$.

Recall that for a prime $p$, $x^p\equiv x \pmod{p}$. ([Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem))  Then, looking modulo 5 we see that
$$P(n)\equiv 3n^5+7n\equiv 3n+7n=10n\equiv 0.$$
Now looking modulo 3 we see that $$P(n)\equiv 5n^3+7n\equiv 5n+7n=12n\equiv 0.$$ Thus $P(n)$ is divisible by 15 for every $n$ as desired.

Comment: Good solution Eric. I thought of FLT but didn't think of applying CRT. Anyhow  +1 for a slick proof.

Comment: No explicit need for the chinese remainder theorem: if a number is a multiple of $3$ and $5$ then it's a multiple of $15$.

Comment: Unfortunately, `\cong` produces $\cong$; for $\equiv$, use `\equiv`.

Comment: Thanks Arturo.  I just got use to \cong from my algebra courses.

Comment: @EricNaslund Can you explain how you had written this
$$5n^3+7 \equiv 5n+7n\pmod3$$ because what I have done is this $$5n^3-5n+7 \equiv 7n \pmod3$$
$$\implies 5n(n+1)(n-1)+7 \equiv 7n \pmod3$$
$$\implies 7\equiv 7n\pmod3$$ but then how's that is possible??

Comment: @SaurabhHota It was a typo: $\:5n^3+\color{#c00}7\:$ should be $\:5n^3 + \color{#C00}{7n}.\:$ I fixed it.

Comment: @BillDubuque oh !!I was too focused at that statement that I forgot to see the post's $P(n)$

Answer (score 20):

**HINT** $\displaystyle\rm\quad \frac{n^5}5\: +\: \frac{n^3}3\: +\: \frac{7\:n}{15}\ =\ \frac{n^5-n}5\: +\: \frac{n^3-n}3\: +\: n\ \in \mathbb Z\ $ by Fermat's Little Theorem.

Answer (score 5):

Taking the lcm we have $\displaystyle \frac{1}{15} \cdot \Bigl[ 3n^{5}+5n^{3} + 7n\Bigr]$ Now show that the quantity $3n^{5} + 5n^{3}+7n$ is always divisible by $15$. Induction may be useful.

Clearly for $n=1$, $3+5+7=15$ is divisible by $15$. Assume that it is true for $n=k$. That is assume that $3k^{5}+5k^{3}+7k$ is divisible by $15$. Use this to show that the quantity

\begin{align*}
3(k+1)^{5}+5(k+1)^{3}+7(k+1) &= 3 \Bigl[k^{5} + {5 \choose 1}k^{4} + \cdots +1\Bigr] + 5(k+1)^{3}+ 7(k+1)
\end{align*}

is divisible by $15$.

Comment: How to read your latex writing? What do I need to use? Thanks

Comment: @Kira: You need to learn latex.There are lot of resources in the web.

Comment: @ Chandru:This is my first time using it and I am not very familiar with it. Can you also show a few more steps in your explanation? Thanks!

Comment: I really don't feel induction is a good way, but I just might not be understanding.  Why will this work immediately?  Anyway, +1 for editing and adding more when the OP asked for help.

Comment: @Eric: Thats the only way which i could think of. Anyway your answer is good to.

Comment: An alternate version of this proof is to show that $3(n+1)^5 + 5(n+1)^3 + 7(n+1) - (3n^5+5n^3+7n)$ is always divisible by 15. As it turns out, this is trivial since once you expand the polynomial out all the coefficients are divisible by 15.