# Find the sum of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory

For any integer $n$ define $k(n) = \frac{n^7}{7} + \frac{n^3}{3} + \frac{11n}{21} + 1$ and $$f(n) = 0 \text{if $k(n)$ is an integer ; $\frac{1}{n^2}$ if $k(n)$ is not an integer } $$

Find $\sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty} f(n)$.

I do not know how to solve such problem of series. So I could not try anything.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This question seems very much familiar to me. where I have seen this question? asked in some exam?

Comment: NBHM 2006 Prob. 5.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

Using Fermat's Little theorem, $$n^p-n\equiv0\pmod p$$  where $p$ is any prime and $n$ is any integer

$\displaystyle\implies n^7-n\equiv0\pmod 7\implies \frac{n^7-n}7$ is an integer

Show that $k(n)$ is integer for all integer $n$

Comment: Thank you Lab. I made a mistake thinking it as an analysis question. Similarly $\frac{n^3 - n}{3}$ is also an integer. So $k(n)$ is always an integer, and the sum is $0$.

Comment: @Samprity, my pleasure. this can be established using induction as well, related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443538/proof-by-induction-that-the-sum-of-terms-is-integer